# order of integration cylindrical volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I got the following integral $$\int_{h}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}A(2-\sin^2\theta)r dr d\theta dz$$

Can I solve it for: $$\int_{h}^{R}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}r dr  dz\int_{0}^{2\pi}A(2-\sin^2\theta) d\theta $$?

Comment: The limits are incorrect since one of the dummy indices, $z$ appears in the outside integral as an integration limit.

Comment: @Dr.MV sorry fixed

Comment: Yes, absolutely, this is in fact a cheap but useful trick that makes computations lighter. Notice, though, that interchanging $r$ and $z$ would completely overhaul your endpoints.

Comment: @AlexM.  Can you please explain more about the interchanging? I did not understand the terminology

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can solve it, except I would think the $$\int_0^{2\pi}A(2-sin^2\theta) d\theta$$ on the outside, before the other two integrals.